# Percolation on infinite percolation clusters

Tags: percolation, pr.probability

Let's consider an infinite percolation cluster $\mathcal{C}_p$ that takes shape in the supercritical phase ($p>p_c$) of a bond percolation in $\mathbb{Z}^d$. What could be said about a bond percolation on $\mathcal{C}_p$ parametrized by $p$ (or parametrized by a $q\ne p$)? Phase caracterizations? Critical values $q_c=f(p)$? Number of infinite clusters if any?

Comment: Can't you just imagine running percolation on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ twice (independently), and losing edges that get deleted either time?  So you're running percolation with parameter $p^2$ (or $pq$)?

Comment: I think you're right John! Nothing interesting is emerging from this percolation :-) I should have thought more carefully before posting this question! 

Comment: It turns out, however, that carrying out percolation on the percolation clusters at criticality leads to an interesting model! http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3603